# Is it possible a git file modification becomes add and delete of same file

Tags: git, diff

I recently got an interesting result from git diff

Ex.  `git diff-tree -r commit1 commit2 | grep file1`
it gives me

```
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 422182cfbe61e33e1f662b554999a02bfbbdbe4a A  file1
:100644 000000 1a7e0e2a3606b613e329979cf632c413897d21cc 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  file1
```

I'm very confused how this would happen. My understanding is it should be

```
:100644 100644 1a7e0e2a3606b613e329979cf632c413897d21cc 422182cfbe61e33e1f662b554999a02bfbbdbe4a M  file1
```

Comment: Is this a public repository? That result does seem odd.